# Parity Error: Transaction gas is too low

Tags: parity, private-blockchain, gas-limit, genesis

In deploying a contract to a private network, I get this error:

> [-32010] Transaction gas is too low. There is not enough gas to cover
>   minimal cost of the transaction (minimal: 84044, got: 5000). Try
>   increasing supplied gas.

Can anyone tell me where this 84044 number is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be a hard-coded number - it'll be the estimation of the gas usage for the transaction, as per [this call](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/82c8dccddf8500550524502ebc1765273ce42798/ethcore/src/miner/transaction_queue.rs#L834) to `estimate_gas_required()`.

(Someone more familiar with the Parity code might want to comment further.)